# Paperclip S3 - Access denied after bucket rename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, amazon-s3, paperclip

So, I have a weird error with Paperclip serving files from Amazon S3...

On my development environment I tested out a change to the name of the bucket, in order to prepare for a migration from my personal S3 account to my business S3 account.

So, I set up the new bucket, copied all the images over from the old one verbatim, and I changed my S3.yml settings file accordingly.

I triple checked and I got the settings for the new bucket correct. Here's the weird part:

Existing files that were copied to the new bucket don't show up, and if I try to load their URL directly I get "access denied". But, if I upload new images through the app they are successfully uploaded to the new bucket and visible in the app without a problem.

So, what am I missing here? How can I restore access to the files that were moved from the old bucket to the new one?

Comment: I think you need to give public view permissions to the files you copied over. I've had to do that before, by going to the s3 console on amazon.com and marking them public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while I don't fully understand why it worked this way, after testing out things more thoroughly it turns out that when the files were copied their permissions were changed to be owner-only. Setting it back to "read = world" fixed everything.